# cancel timeOut in JavaScript with a button

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

i'm trying to stop a setTimeout with a button within my game but when i click on the button I go back to the menu and the timer continue. Can somebody help me ?

P.s. I cutted a ;lot of code in the middle to make it smaller

```
       this.stop();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // gestion du temps
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.leTimeOut = window.setTimeout(punir.bind(this), 31000);
    this.lInterval = window.setInterval(afficherTemps.bind(this), 1000);
/////////////////////////
Cutted section
////////////////////////

        console.info("!!! "+nbMatchs+" !!!");
        this.txtItems.text = ""+(6-nbMatchs);

        if(nbMatchs == 6){
            window.clearTimeout(this.leTimeOut);
            this.gotoAndStop("FinNiveau1");
        }

        return bonnePosition;
    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Fonction pour lancer la punition
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function punir(evt){
        console.log("temps écoulé"); 
        this.gotoAndStop("EchecNiveau1");
    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Fonction d'affichage du temps
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.txtTimer.text = "29";
    function afficherTemps(evt){
        this.txtTimer.text = parseInt(this.txtTimer.text)-1;
    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Fonction et écouteur du bouton Annuler
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.btRetour.evenementClick = this.btRetour.on("click", onClicA);
    function onClicA(evt) {
        console.log("retour au menu");
        clearTimeOut(this.leTimeOut);   
        evt.remove(); //retrait de l'écouteur (la méthode facile!)
        this.parent.gotoAndStop("Intro");

    }
```

Comment: Can you put your code in the question as a code block? Looking at code from an image is very difficult to work with.

Comment: You should provide the code. Otherwise, you collect downvotes

Comment: there you go. should be better now

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly copies your 'clearTimeout'
is clearTimeOut and and the o in timeout shouldn't be capitalized

Comment: soory my bad I changed it when I was trying to find the error, but i just changed it back and when i click on the button i still get the losing screen 30sec later.

Comment: The next thing i would check is if the timerId's are the same so when you first declare `this.leTimeOut` i would put a `console.log(this.leTimeOut)` right below it and also do the same thing before you call 
`clearTimeOut(this.leTimeOut)` and make sure they return the same id in the console

Comment: thanks to your idea I found the problem. To put it simply, during my clearTimeOut, i needed to put (this.parent.ltTimeOut) to make it work.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that worked, usually always something dumb causing the issue lol and console logging can be your best friend in finding out what it is